# YAML to Dropdown List

Tags: drop-down-menu, yaml, react-dropdown-tree-select

I am a Linux Admin. Say I have a big yaml file and I want to host it on a webpage on a Linux server in the form of a tree like structure, Exactly just like what windows registry tool REGEDIT looks like. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, is there any freeware tools or source code available that will provide this? I am open to using the source file in a different format other than yaml.

Comment: Since YAML generally models a graph, not a tree, such a UI would be ill-equipped to display every potential YAML structure. But if you're sure your YAML never uses anchors, aliases, tags or non-string keys, chances are you can convert it to JSON and find a tool that can render such a UI for JSON data.

Comment: Thanks @flyx . I am sure my yaml file will never use anchors, aliases, tags or non-string keys. I could use a JSON file too. is there a tool that you know which will render such a UI.

Comment: No but lots of templating engines take such a JSON/YAML structure as input so it should be trivial to write a template that outputs HTML when given JSON/YAML data as input.